# I have master file in project still it says master file not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have master file in my project and on execution it gave me error that it couldn't find my master file. It shows assemblies or refernce missing but there is no place were I can add refernces. Please help!!

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gamHr.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not underneath ~/TERRMaster.Master it is in ~/TERRWebProject/TERRMaster.Master

Comment: MasterPageFile="~/TERRWebProject/TERRMaster.Master"

Comment: However, when you publish it, it may not be right depending on where it resides in the actual website.  You have some kind of funky project directory structure setup here.

Comment: thanks pal!! Thanks a billion.. that worked. I don't know how I over looked that and yeah it is little weird but I have told work in this way..
U know it is like, code ->  business -> data access; file.